# How to approach estimating correction size in the BK equation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, quantum-chromodynamics, estimation

I am starting to do work in theoretical physics, and as a test, the professor I am working with asked me to estimate the size of a correction to an approximate solution to the BK equation. I am no really sure how to approach this, as I first tried to plug in the approximation, but found that the integral was still unsolvable. I was thinking using something along the lined of the Euler approximation, but I am still a little bit lost. I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: Apparently dimensional analysis was the best way forward

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is by dimensional analysis